# PhpStorm - print out methods and variables in class files

Tags: phpstorm

I have about 10 classes all in individual files. I have not looked at them for ages. Is there a PhpStorm function that would allow me to list the methods and attributes listed in the individual files?

EDIT: The solution is to highlight all the classes you are interested in and then use the diagram tool. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally discovered what I was looking for.

Highlight all the classes you are interested in in Project view. Right click Diagrams->Show Diagrams (or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U).

Arrange diagrams on screen.

Select light colored background (Ctrl Backtick) select 5: Look and Feel (not theme).

Right click on diagram and do a print preview. Select Graph for full size. Click OK and make page adjustments. I printed out my 8 classes on an 11 x 17 sheet and I am in "help-my-bad-memory-heaven". Just what I was looking for.

Hope that was useful.[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use PHPStorm's Structure View:

> Use the Structure pop-up window or the Structure tool window to quickly jump to the desired member of a file in the editor. The Structure views provide quick navigation for all supported file types.

[image: Structure View]

> You can also use the Structure tool window (Alt+7). This view is flexibly configurable and useful for many tasks, apart from navigation. However, the File Structure pop-up window is the easiest way for quick navigation.

Source https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/navigating-with-structure-views.html

Comment: Gordon thanks for that. I have the world's worst memory so I want to be able to stick this up on the wall. Is there any way of printing out these windows and/or printing out a single report? That was really what I was looking for -- a single listing with file, attributes  and methods that I can use as a sort of "offline" reference. I doubt it is there but one can always believe in the miracle of Christmas....

Comment: Yep looks like I should get into phpDoc but that is ANOTHER learning job. Anyhow I hacked with it screen grabs and pasting into a Word document. Anything but ideal but a 5 min job so what the heck!

Comment: The answer is to select ALL the relevant classes and click diagram. See answer I have added. This solution is obviously great for checking out one class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHPDoc for that. Generate API doc of your comment doc and you have a offline reference very useful and like your code.

Otherwise, you can attribute a shortcut for launch or focus on the structure view PHPStorm tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is a point called 'Navigate' at the top menu within which there are 'Method Hierarchy' and 'Call Hieararhy'. It is not totally the same what I need, but I do see list of methods called by the current method.