# How to prevent IDE (PhpStorm) writing to DB while editing code? And a ghost variable

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, insert, phpstorm

This is probably a stupendously dumb question.

I am hacking away at code relearning mySQL and PHP. I am starting with a simple form and a simple processing page which has the following code on it.

```
$firstName=$_GET['firstName'];
$sql = $pdo->prepare("insert into person (firstName) values (:firstName)");
$sql->bindParam(":firstName", $firstName);
$sql->execute();
```

My problem is that when I change the form page or the processing page at all (even indenting or changing a single letter of text) the debugger checks and the `INSERT` statement "fires". So I have dozens of unwanted entries in the DB.

Is there a way of making this just "fire" when I do an actual `submit` from the form? Obviously I can break the DB connection but rather defeats the whole point of the learning curve I am on.

Grateful for any thoughts.

I am posting a related question on the ghost variable but thought I should keep them separate. [Ghost variables in PhpStorm.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479256/phpstorm-listing-methods-and-variables-in-class-files)

Comment: I can't imagine that PHPstorm executes your code on editing. May be you refrech your page to see changes? As you use `GET` to update a database it will insert a row on every page reload. Try to change your code to make DB changes only on `POST`

Comment: In debug mode it refreshes the page(s) live so you can see errors - very very useful. Did not see how changing the form method from GET to POST would change things and sadly it made no difference. The SELECT will surely "fire" on any page load.

Comment: @OldMauiMan Are you using LiveEdit plugin and in debug session? That's the only explanation I can come with -- when you edit your page LiveEdit tries to refresh it .. and since it's a PHP file it will re-execute it. That's why you should do what @GennadiyLitvinyuk have stated in his answer: 1) only use `GET` requests to display your data; 2) only use `POST` to save new/modified data 3) if you need to display results after post -- redirect to the page that will be served via `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

When using **LiveEdit** plugin of **PHPStorm** you should take care of correct implementing `GET` and `POST` requests.

The HTTP protocol defines `GET`-type requests as being idempotent, while `POST`s may have side effects. In plain English, that means that `GET` is used for viewing something, without changing it, while `POST` is used for changing something.

For example, a product page should use `GET`, because page refreshes should make no changes on backend, while a form that makes checkout (saving order, accepting payment, reducing rests) should use `POST`.

In your case you should first check for `POST`:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
  $sql = $pdo->prepare('insert into person (firstName) values (:firstName)');
  $sql->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName);
  $sql->execute();
}
```

Comment: Sorry not following this at all. The only GET and/or POST I have are sending data from a `form` to a "process" page. If I edit the process page that is when more info is inserted into the database irrespective of if I use POST or GET. The only place GET/POST is being used is as the `method` for a `form`. I suppose I could rewrite the form and pass a JSON via  .... But I had a similar problem with Dreamweaver. It seems debugging "reprocesses" the whole page leading to the `INSERT` statement going again.

Comment: It does not matter which editor you use - you should update database only on `POST`.

Comment: OK I understand what your are saying but I still have the problem. Also the call to the database is NOT done by a form call that is done by a PDO object so the GET or POST is only passing variables (the principal difference being in the formation of the URL). I cannot see how the P/G question will affect the PDO call as all the P/G is doing is passing a variable from one page to another. In something like an AJAX request yes I see the difference but here in a very traditional HTML form setting I really cannot see the difference and as I said it makes NO DIFFERENCE to the problem I'm having.